# Delete files on a Raspberry Pi with Python script - permission error

Tags: python, file, raspberry-pi, sudo

I have a script on my RasPi that on startup is in charge of moving and erasing a bunch of old files.

The script, named "erasePi.py" is called from rc.local

I have had some issues in the past few days with this script, lacking required permissions to erase and copy files.

At the end, I've found I was calling erasePi.py from rc.local with the following line:
`sudo python /home/.../erasePi.py`

and I changed with:
`python /home/.../erasePi.py`

since all the scripts run from rc.local have root permissions.

Everything working now, but I would like to ask if this solution is a coincidence of various factors or simply, with that `sudo` I was triggering an abnormal behavior of Raspbian?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that the sudo command was the issue.

As you mentioned in your comment, rc.local file has root permissions. So it is not necessary to include sudo command.

I hope this comment helps you

Kind regards

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).